# JavaScript project not writing to document

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript at school, and this project isn't doing what I want it to do. (which is the reason for these posts in the first place, right?)

The goal is to have the user enter words one at a time with prompt in a function called startMeUp(), which then stops prompting when the user enters an empty string. (that part works)

It's then supposed to refer to a function "processString" that turns the inputted strings into an array, checks the length of each word in the array, and turns it uppercase if < 4 letters or lowercase if >= 4.

Finally, it's supposed to "return the converted string to a variable in the calling function startMeUp, and display the value using document.write"

I thought i was doing it correctly, but nothing is writing to the page, so i'm not sure where i've gone wrong. I've included the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Exercise 2</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
//************************
// Main start-up function
// Invoked from the onload event
var someInput;
var someArray;
var someFinalString;

function startMeUp() {
    do{
        someInput = prompt("Enter a word");
    }

    while(someInput.length > 0);
    processString(someInput);
    document.write(someFinalString);


}

function processString(someInput){
    //split the input string into a JavaScript array
    someArray = someInput.split(" ");
    //use a for loop to examine every word
    for(i = 0; someArray[x]; i++)
    {
        if(someArray[i].length < 4)
        {
            someArray[i].toUpperCase();
        }

        if(someArray[i].length >= 4)
        {
            someArray[i].toLowerCase();
        }

        someFinalString = someArray.join(" ");
    }


}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="startMeUp();">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should check your console for any errors when code does not work as intended

Comment: Calling `someArray[i].toUpperCase()` won't alter the value of `someArray[i]` - it'll just find the value and then discard it. You'll need to assign that value to the array element.

Comment: @jsheeran thats true but that should still print something, unless there is more prominent issue. Hint, `someArray[x]`

Comment: @Rajesh whoops, i had missed that! now it's just printing 'undefined'

Comment: @jsheeran how do i do that?

Comment: @kayyteaa the console.log() function lets you log stuff to console. To check the console, you can use developer tools in Chrome. You can also use developer tools in Chrome to debug your code step by step to figure out what might be going wrong.

Comment: Using a global `var someFinalString` and modifying it in a helper function is usually not the best way to go. I think it would be better to change `processString` to be called `buildString` or something and explicitly return a new string as an output value. Also, it's weird that you run `someFinalString = someArray.join(" ");` every time in the loop instead of just once in the function after the loop is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of desire behavior.

```
function start() {
    var input = "";
  var str = "";
    do {
      input = prompt("Enter a word");
      str += input + " ";
    } while (input);
    document.write(proccessStr(str));
}
function proccessStr (str) {
  var arr = str.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length < 4)
      arr[i] = arr[i].toUpperCase();
    else
      arr[i] = arr[i].toLowerCase();
  }
  return arr.join(" ");
} 
start();
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXByby (jsfiddle does'nt support `docuent.write`).

Few problems with your code.

1. You are using global variables without no need, not good practice
2. You don't save the all input from the user, so always the last string is saved, and that the empty string, so actually you send an empty string to your other function.
3. When you use `string` methods on string, it does'nt change the value inside the variable, it just creates new one, you need to assign it to the variable that holds the value in order to change it.
4. If look at my example, I used `return` to return the value of the transformed string to the first function, no need of global.
5. though I used `document.write` , it's not good practice , consider write to an element `innerHTML/Text`